# How can I programmatically obtain the hash of latest built Git revision of a Jenkins project?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am accessing the project from a Jenkins plugin, so I have access to an instance of hudson.model.Project. I know that Git is the used SCM. Is there a nice (non-hacky) way to access the last built revision?

Some details:

I am not interested in success or failure of the build, it's enough that the build was started.

"Revision": I know the Git URL and branch already, the hash of the revision that was or will be checked out for the build is needed.

I know that Git plugin sets the environment variable "GIT_COMMIT". I consider this as one of the hacky options.

Answer (score 0):

If you are cloning/accessing the repository on some build step - you may want to use

```
COMMIT=`git rev-parse HEAD`
```

during the build and for example export this variable to build description or echo it into a file and archive it as a build artifact.

Comment: As I am writing a plugin, I cannot add things to a build easily. It's about accesing it directly from Java. Meanwhile I found out that jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.SCMRevisionImpl contains the hash. Using environment variables for this purpose is unappropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I must have paid more attention when reading the question.